# Conditional MIN query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the lowest price of some objects - works.
Problem is i not only need the lowest price but have also to consider following conditions:

- if the prices are all in the past, then get me simply the lowest
- if some of the prices are today and/or in the future, then exclude prices from the past i get me only the lowest of today and/or in the future

I tried something with HAVING and CASE WHEN but thats crap i guess.

So the correct answer for the data below would be

```
3, 10, 500
5, 20, 410
7, 30, 110
```

---

```
Table

pid, oid, price, date
1, 10, 300, 2013-09-01
2, 10, 400, 2014-09-01
3, 10, 500, 2016-09-01
4, 20, 310, 2013-10-01
5, 20, 410, 2017-10-01
6, 20, 510, 2018-10-01
7, 30, 110, 2012-10-01
8, 40, 120, 2013-10-01
```

---

```
Query

SELECT  pid, oid, min(price) AS price
FROM prices
GROUP BY oid
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: data is pretty simple i think

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
SELECT p.oid, COALESCE(fp.price, pp.price) AS price
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT oid FROM prices) p
LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT oid, min(price) AS price
  FROM prices
  WHERE date>=CURDATE()
  GROUP BY oid) fp
ON p.oid=fp.oid
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT oid, min(price) AS price
  FROM prices
  WHERE date<CURDATE()
  GROUP BY oid) pp
ON p.oid=pp.oid
```